# Can't connect to the instance in private subnet through a ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I would like to build a simple AWS structure just like the picture. But I failed to connect the instance by using tera term. I checked everything but cannot find anything wrong, can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- routing tables
- security groups
- VPC flow logs
- etc.

Try to fix it in the console and when it works do the same in TerraForm or CloudFormation.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The question seems to be about "tera term" -- an SSH client -- which would be a problem if that is what OP is trying to use to communicate through an ALB.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ah, I misread that. I didn't expect "tera term" in this context ;)